# Presenting UIViewController from SKScene?

Tags: facebook, swift, twitter, sprite-kit

So at the beginning I was having trouble implementing social media sharing into my project using Swift/Sprite-Kit. I believe I have now accomplished that but I just cannot trigger the methods, or as it seems everybody's struggle, I cannot present the view controller from my SKScene. So what I first did, was to create my buttons on my EndGame Scene. Then on my touchesEnded method I called the NSNotificationCenter. Something like this:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit
import Social

class EndGameScene: SKScene {

var facebookButton: SKNode! = nil
var twitterButton: SKNode! = nil


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)

    // FacebookButton
    facebookButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "facebookButton")
    facebookButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.3 , y: self.size.height * 0.45);
    addChild(facebookButton)

    // TwitterButton
    twitterButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "twitterButton")
    twitterButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.5 , y: self.size.height * 0.45);
    addChild(twitterButton)


}

override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if facebookButton.containsPoint(location) {
           NSLog("Button tapped")
           NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("FacebookID", object: nil)

        }

        if twitterButton.containsPoint(location) {
            NSLog("Button tapped")
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("TwitterID", object: nil)

        }


    }

}
```

Then I created my SocialViewController with the methods that are supposed to be triggered with help of the NSNotificationCenter to show the sheets. This is the code I used for it:

```
import UIKit
import Social

class SocialViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showTweetSheet", name: "TwitterID", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showFacebookSheet", name: "FacebookID", object: nil)
}

func showTweetSheet() {
    let tweetSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = {
        result in
        switch result {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled:
            break
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done:
            break
        }
    }

    tweetSheet.setInitialText("Test Twitter")
    tweetSheet.addImage(UIImage(named: "TestImage.png"))
    tweetSheet.addURL(NSURL(string: "http://twitter.com"))
    self.presentViewController(tweetSheet, animated: false, completion: {
    })
}

func showFacebookSheet() {
    let facebookSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    facebookSheet.completionHandler = {
        result in
        switch result {
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled:
            break
        case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done:
            break
        }
    }
    facebookSheet.setInitialText("Test Facebook")
    facebookSheet.addImage(UIImage(named: "TestImage.png")) 
    facebookSheet.addURL(NSURL(string: "http://facebook.com")) 
    self.presentViewController(facebookSheet, animated: false, completion: {
    })
}
```

I literally have no idea on what I might be missing or doing wrong. I've read several posts on this and using the NSNotificationCenter is supposed to be the best way to accomplish this but seems is not working for me. So if there is anyone there that could help me out I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can download the Facebook Sdk from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk. And after create the key hash using your cmd prompt. For more details for create the key hash see the link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: Well thank you! But I am looking to do this for Swift and Sprite kit